# CastHelloText on IOS doesn't update screen with text

Tags: ios, google-cast

I've successfully built the IOS app, `added the correct APP_ID and registered my Chromecast`. I used the default Styled Media Receiver as indicated in the readme. So no customization.
When I run the app though, this is what i see.

```
2014-02-04 21:25:09.523 HelloTextGoogleCast[18374:70b] device found!! TVCast
2014-02-04 21:25:12.818 HelloTextGoogleCast[18374:70b] Selecting device:TVCast
2014-02-04 21:25:13.492 HelloTextGoogleCast[18374:70b] connected!!
2014-02-04 21:25:14.705 HelloTextGoogleCast[18374:70b] application has launched
2014-02-04 21:25:26.817 HelloTextGoogleCast[18374:70b] sending text VBBBC
```

However, **the text does not appear on the screen.**
Just a small blue outline logo appears
What am I missing?

The CastHelloVideo sample on IOS seems to work fine though using same App ID

Comment: If this problem still exists, please open a bug on Github for that project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated the README.md in Cast-HelloText-ios to mention that you need to use custom receiver.

Now the text mentions...
Register an application on the Developers Console http://cast.google.com/publish. Select the Custom Receiver option and specify the URL to where you are hosting the receiver.html file.

https://github.com/googlecast/CastHelloText-ios/blob/master/README.md

Comment: It had me fooled when it said the easiest way was to use the Styled Media Receiver. Thanks for fixing the Readme

Answer (score 0):

I have some questions... I can't get the sample application working...

1. When registering the App at http://cast.google.com/publish does the app name need to HelloTextGoogleCast.app and is it case sensitive?
2. The read me says "Setup the project dependencies in xCode". What do you mean? I have the application compiling after pointing to the GoogleCast Framework and I have changed the line to reflect my app ID.
3. The read me says to change the App ID in "ChromecastDeviceController.m" only this file does not exist. it should be "HTGCViewController.m" and specifically line 18.

hunt and peck continues...

... some progress. the Serial number of my ChromeCast ... looks like it ends in a 6 - not 8 as I thought. So some progress.

Now the receiver.html file is being displayed on screen as code - why?
[this is because the URL for the receiver.html file on GoogleDrive is incorrect.]
To get the correct url, you need to preview the file care of the Chrome browser (the preview function does not seem to work in Safari).

- so get the right URL and it all hangs together...
  Here's my URL... yours should follow the same syntax.
  https://googledrive.com/host/0B-G72FpwPXc2TFNmcEhpTzFHUVU/receiver.html

And it's all working now.